# How can we print a list of todos specific to particular user when he/she log in on thyme leaf view page

Tags: list, spring-boot, authentication, thymeleaf, display

I am making a todo app using spring boot where a user registers and  then logs in(using spring security) and he/she is able to see a list of user-specific todos  when he/she logs in, but I am unable to get a list of todo on the view page, Can anyone help me out what I am missing or where I am doing wrong

Below is the output I am getting :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRwbT.png)

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
package net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.security;

import net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/registration**",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/img/**",
                        "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean

    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

}
```

Here is my DAO layer :

**TodoRepository.java**

```
package net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.repository;

import net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.model.Todo;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface TodoRepository extends CrudRepository<Todo, Long> {

    @Query("Select t.taskId, u.email, t.taskName FROM Todo t INNER JOIN User u ON t.user.userId= u.userId where u.email = :email")
    List<Todo> findByEmail(@Param(value="email") String email);

}
```

Below is my service layer:

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
package net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.service;

import net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.dto.UserRegistrationDto;
import net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.model.Role;
import net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.model.User;
import net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{


    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Override
    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    @Override
    public User save(UserRegistrationDto registration) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName(registration.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(registration.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(registration.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registration.getPassword()));
        user.setRole(Arrays.asList(new Role("ROLE_USER")));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(),
                user.getPassword(),
                mapRolesToAuthorities(user.getRole()));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles) {

        return roles.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**TodoServiceImpl.java**

```
import net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.model.Todo;
import net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.repository.TodoRepository;
import net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class TodoServiceImpl implements TodoService{


    @Autowired
    private TodoRepository todoRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Todo> findByEmail(String email) {
        return todoRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }
}
```

Controller :

**LoginController.java**

```
package net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.controller;

import net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.model.Todo;
import net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.service.TodoService;
import net.guides.springboot.todomanagement.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private TodoService todoService;


    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        return "Login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String loginUser(UserDetails userDetails,Model model) {
        System.out.println(userDetails.getUsername());

        return "redirect:/info";
    }

    @GetMapping ("/info")
    public String userIndex(UserDetails userDetails, Model model) {

        String email = userDetails.getUsername();
        List<Todo> todoList = todoService.findByEmail(userDetails.getUsername());
        System.out.println(todoList);
        model.addAttribute("todoList",todoList);
        model.addAttribute("username",email);
        return "Index";
    }

}
```

view page:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" th:href="@{/}">Registration and
                Login Module</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"><a th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <h2>User Registration and Login Module using Spring Boot, Spring
        MVC, Spring Security, JPA/Hibernate and Thymeleaf</h2>

    <p>
        Welcome <span sec:authentication="username">User</span>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="container my-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 mt-5 mb-5">


                        <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-md">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Task Name</th>
                                <th>Task Description</th>
                                <th>Target Date</th>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="todo : ${todoList}">
                                <td th:text="${todo.taskName}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${todo.taskDesc}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${todo.targetDate}"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a th:href="@{/edit/{id}(id=${todo.taskId})}"
                                       class="btn btn-primary">
                                        <i class="fas fa-user-edit ml-2"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a th:href="@{/delete/{id}(id=${todo.taskId})}"
                                       class="btn btn-primary">
                                        <i class="fas fa-user-times ml-2"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the `System.out.println(todoList);` print out the list?

Comment: No its not ,when i login and sees the index page its not printing anything on the console

Comment: Have you tried adding `@AuthenticationPrincipal` to the `UserDetails userDetails` parameter in the controller methods?

Comment: Yes tried now with @AuthenticationPrincipal with UserDetails userDetails paramter, but still getting no list on UI and no data on console, please assist me.